# C# doesn't throw NullReferenceException at developer machine

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a code which looks like this:

```
public partical class frmXXX : Form
{

  SomeObject foo = null;

  public void XYZ()
  {
    foo.ABC.DEF(foo.XXX, foo.YYY, foo.ZZZ);
    somethingElse();
  }

  ...

}
```

It appears that I had a bug where I called `XYZ()` when `foo` is null. The program crashed with a NullReferenceException at the customer, which is what I would expect. However, on my development machine I do not get an Exception. I also verified with the debugger that foo is actually null. The debugger says that it is null.

Once the null object was invoked, the method will end, so `somethingElse();` is not called. It is like a silent exception. Is there a chance that my development machine is wrongly configured, or do I enable something?

Comment: checked vs debug exception settings?

Comment: How have you got your exceptions configured, particularly for `System.NullReferenceException`, in terms of breaking on thrown/unhandled?

Comment: Where can I find these settings? I am quite new to C#

Comment: what is `public ==>partical<== class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cntrl + Alt + E** (Or **Debug -> Exceptions** or in VS2017 **Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings**)
Select **Reset All**, this will return the default exceptions.

Also make sure **Just My Code** is checked. You can find this under **Debug -> Options**. This will bring you to the **Debugger -> General** options. Here you can check **Just My Code**.

Comment: Thank you! Though I had to explicitly check **"Common Language Runtime Exceptions" --> System.NullReferenceException** . It appears that this kind of Exception is ignored by default in Visual Studio 2015 ! (Which is kinda shocking)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put TryCatch to this:

```
public void XYZ()
  {

///try here
{
        foo.ABC.DEF(foo.XXX, foo.YYY, foo.ZZZ);
}
  ///catch
{
   return error here................
}
    somethingElse();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your exception settings set to something that isn't default. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a useful link to both how to revert to default and how to tune the settings to your needs.

you can check your settings with **Ctrl + Alt + E** on vs 2015 - 2017